# Сборка небольшого проекта из GitHub

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток.
Собираю проект https://github.com/leonahi/stream_cipher_a5_1 в Qt(проект без Qt, C++, MinGw 32bit)
[image: Проект в папке]

Создаю проект c qMake, main.cpp не заменяю
[image]

Добавляю все файлы из папки
[image]

Компилирую
[image]

Срабатывает условие :

```
/*
     *
 * Read plain text from binary file - argv[1]
 *
 */
if(argc != 2)
{
    cout<<"Error: Input file not found"<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Ккак мне нужно выполнить чтение из файла если с проектом прилагается **test_file_binary.txt**?

Comment: передать его в аргументах командной строки, очевидно...

Comment: В смысле это как?

Comment: Допустим у вас скомпилировался проект и получился бинарник a.exe, вам нужно запустить его из командной строки командой: "a.exe test_file_binary.txt", тогда программе передастсе имя файла и всё будет работать.

Comment: @Gunik если интересует решение в рамках IDE, то где-то там в настройках проекта должна быть настройка вроде «параметров запуска»

Comment: @ zcorvid попробовал.` Error: Unable to open filetest_file_binary.txt ` пишет в командной строке

Comment: А test_file_binary.txt лежит рядом с бинарником? Если нет - нужно путь к нему указывать. А вообще без кода открытия файла трудно пытаться понять причину... Указанная ошибка означает, что файл открыть не удалось, скорее всего его попросту нету там, где ожидает программа.

Comment: в настройках проекта в разделе запуск там где аргументы запуска укажите полный путь до файла и из IDE можете запустить

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил попробовать "собрать" ваш пример. Работаю тоже в "Qt" :3.

Разобью на действия :

**1. Скачал проект**

**2. Разархивировал проект**

**3. В той же директории  создал проект на С++** (вторая картинка)

**4. После чего добавил в проект все файлы кроме `Makefile` файла. Я так и не
   понял в чём именно был собран скачанный проект и не стал
   заворачиваться с ним**

**5. Также заменил файл `main.cpp` на разархивированный из проекта.Можно
   также просто скопировать вставить с заменой всего содержимого.**

**6. Воаля всё собирается :3**

**7. Также желательно в ту папку в которой лежит собранный проект** (в винде
   .exe, в линуксе ?? ) **положить тестовые текстовые файлы** (.txt)

**8. В винде : После чего можно зайти в командную строку (cmd) и зайти в
   папку в которой собран проект (через cmd разумеется) и ввести

   команду `exper.exe test_file_binary.txt`**

---

В линуксе всё печальней :(

Выполняем все действия до 7 пункта. После чего сталкиваемся что исполнительного файла как такового полностью нету. В винде .exe файл при "запуске" сразу говорит каких файлов тебе не хватает после чего, ты просто копируешь их из папки где лежит компилятор в директорию собранного проекта. В  линуксе надо устанавливать [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt#linuxdeployqt------) (`sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`) после чего выполнять команду подтягивающую библиотеки, но увы у меня не вышло (третья картинка), притом что у меня linuxdeployqt установился.

Я пошёл другим путем, просто "загрубил" программу и закоментировал все вызовы `argv[1]` заменив их созданным буфером с названием файла(который лежит в директории программы ) `char ess[256] = "test_file_binary.txt";`

К примеру :

```
//    ifstream file(argv[1]);
ifstream file(ess);
```

Ну и вот картинка с результатом.

[image: ура результат]

---

Создаю проект. 
[image: первая картинка]
Ошибка :(
[image: вторая картинка]